# Windows 10 Ghost Process at Startup?

Tags: windows

Since Windows 1803 installed in a tablet (32-bit Windows) on Friday, I get a task with no name at startup, which runs for 5-10 minutes. Task Manager shows it as a "Windows Task" and it typically uses 0.1% CPU almost continuously (occasionally dropping to 0 for a short time). TM shows no memory, disk, or network usage (though it might just be small enough that it doesn't round up to 0.1%). The task literally has no name, and no properties or other details when investigated with right-click. It does NOT show up in the "Details" tab of TM, only Processes. Defender doesn't complain about it. I'll be downloading Malwarebytes for a scan later today, and will revisit my W10Privacy settings, but has anybody else noticed this and have any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a tool called process explorer to locate the binary file for the process and get some more details. Post those details and it might give us some more informations about this process.

Answer (score 0):

The task could be a quick scan by Defender itself, or a continuation of the update: MS now completes, "portions of the work [previously] done during the offline phases and [placed it in the online phase](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3264019/microsoft-windows/microsoft-shrinks-windows-10s-upgrade-downtime.html)."  To find out what processes start at boot, use Sysinternals' [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) (now a Microsoft product).

[image: Sysinternals' Autoruns]

This tool shows the processes in each startup category and in total, a VirusTotal scan, if enabled, and additional information.

It also enables you to disable automatic starting of a process temporarily or permanently. Use this to test if a task you suspect is the cause of the issue, **but use caution**. Check what a task does *before* disabling it, as a mistake might prevent booting. It is also a good idea to make a Restore Point, or better, a disk image, before making major changes.